# Define a macro to be run at global scope without warnings

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, global-scope

The following code is OK, but I get a warning due to the extra ';' after INIT.

```
#define INIT \
    namespace Vars { \
      int a = 0; \
    }

INIT;

int main() { ... }
```

How can I fix this code, allowing the notation with the extra ';'?

Consider that INIT must be callable at global scope.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why do you need to add a `;` there? Why do you need a macro in the first place?

Comment: What compiler are you using? ideone c++14 did not complain for me. Although I am not sure of the warning level. http://ideone.com/4VzHaL

Comment: @drescherjm: It requires `-Wpedantic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seems to be reasonable:

```
#define INIT \
    namespace Vars { \
      int a = 0; \
    } int INIT_ = 0

INIT;

int main() { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** want to force the semicolon, one possible workaround is defining an unused `struct` with a "unique" name, like this:

```
#define CAT_IMPL(m0, m1) m0##m1
#define CAT(m0, m1) CAT_IMPL(m0, m1)

#define INIT \
    namespace Vars { \
      \
    } \
    struct CAT(some_unique_name, __LINE__) \
    { } __attribute__((unused))

INIT;
INIT;

int main() { }
```

[Coliru example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ee61bd00b03f715).

Comment: That's neat, but notice that it breaks compatibility with MSVC.

Comment: Thank you Vittorio, but I would say that instead of using that slightly cryptic code I prefer to get the warning.

Comment: @Pietro: if you are satisfied, do you mind accepting this answer so that the question can be marked as "solved"? Thanks. Alternatively, you can post your own answer and accept it.